# Js/jQuery function doesn't work on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

**/!\ Edited /!\** 

Basically I have an **html table** and I want to **add entries** to this table. So I have functions that can **add a row on top or bottom** a particular row. Fot that I call a function that will **append a form with `display = table-row`** and I have an event on this form sothat I can handle the submit with jQuery. 
So :

I have a table with several rows and for each row I have a cell with `onclick`event like :

```
<td class="edit_td"> <span class="edit2 up" onclick="addTop(\'' + child[0] + '_child_id' + '\')"></span> <span class="edit2 down" onclick="addBottom(\'' + child[0] + '_child_id' + '\')"></span> <a class="delete2" href="#" onclick="removeChildFromStructure(\'' + $('#dyn_struct_id').html() + '\', \'' + child[0] + '\')"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></td>
```

And then for example I have the `addTop` function which is :

```
function addTop(rowId)
{
    console.log("ROW ID = " + rowId);

    // We can add only one row at the same time
    if($('#structure_tbody > form.new_tr').length){return -1;}

    // Some hidden data
    var brol = '<input type="hidden" id="isChildUpdate" name="isChildUpdate" value="false"/>';
    brol += '<input type="hidden" id="parent_id" name="parent_id" value="' + $('#dyn_struct_id').text() + '"/>';
    brol += '<input type="hidden" id="child_id" name="child_id" value="-1"/>';
    console.log("BROL = " + brol);

    // This will be the identifier of the new created row
    var new_row_id = (($('#' + rowId).index() + ($('#' + rowId).index() - 1)) / 2) + 1;
    console.log("NEW_ROW_ID = " + new_row_id);

    // Id of the copied row element
    var childId = rowId.split('_')[0];
    console.log("CHILD ID = " + childId);

    var form = $('<form id="add_structure_child_row" class="new_tr tr-form" name="add_update_child_form"></form>');
    form.append('<td class="struct_id_field"><input type="hidden" id="new_place_id" name="new_place_id" value="' + new_row_id + '"/><span>#</span></td>');
    form.append('<td id="' + childId + '_child_tag_copy"><input class="no-spaces-no-null" type="text" name="add_update_child_tag" id="add_update_child_tag" placeholder="Ex.: BDP" autofocus/></td>');
    form.append('<td id="' + childId + '_child_opt_copy"><input type="checkbox" id="add_update_child_optional" name="add_update_child_optional"/></td>');
    form.append('<td id="' + childId + '_child_rep_copy"><input type="checkbox" id="add_update_child_repetitif" name="add_update_child_repetitif"/></td>');
    form.append('<td id="' + childId + '_child_struct_copy"><select name="add_update_child_id" id="add_update_child_id"></select></td>');
    form.append('<td id="' + childId + '_child_description_copy"><input type="text" name="add_update_child_descr" id="add_update_child_descr" placeholder="Description"/></td>');
    form.append('<td id="' + childId + '_auteur_email_copy"><span class="disabled">Auteur</span></td>');
    form.append('<td id="' + childId + '_child_modif_date_copy"><span class="disabled">Date</span></td>');
    form.append('<td class="edit2_td">' + brol + '<button type="submit" class="edit3 little-btn-submit" form="add_structure_child_row" href="#" name="add_update_doc_submit"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button><button type="button" href="#" onclick="removeRow()" class="delete3 little-btn-delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>');

    console.log("FORM = " + $(form).html());

    $(form).insertBefore($('#' + rowId));
    $('#add_update_child_id').select2({tags:true}).select2('val', '-1');
    populateSelect('add_update_child_id', 'structures');

    console.log("--- END ---");
}
```

And the problem is that my code works well (the form that has `display = table-cell` appends to the table) on : 
Chrome : tested on Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
IE : tested on Version 11.0.9600.18665

But not on Firefox (tested on version 49.0.2)

The output of `console.log(...)` that this method contains is the same on firefox and chrome. I can see that firefox added the form to the table but he doesn't show it : 
[image]

Comment: Try clearing the cache of the Firefox.

Comment: You could already replace lines 4 to 13 with `if($('#structure_tbody > form.new_tr').length) return -1` . Also, define "It doesn't work well"

Comment: @JeremyThille Well, it doesn't work at all. It doesn't append the form (the form added to the table has `display: table-row`. But there is no error in the console....

Comment: Any errors in the console? What if you `console.log(rowId)` ?